# A custom for in statement

Tags: javascript

[This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) has the example:

```
for (var name in buz) {
   if (buz.hasOwnProperty(name)) {}
}
```

To protect against seeing things in the prototype.  This hack has made the "for in" statement all but useless in JavaScript.  The current advice is to not use "for in".

Q: Is it possible to write a custom "for in" function that automatically includes the if (buz.hasOwnProperty(name)) {} condition?

I'm thinking of something like:

```
window.whatFor = function(variable,object) {
   for (var variable in object) [
      if (object.hasOwnProperty(variable) {
         do something here
      }
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
whatFor(name,buz) {
do something here 
}
```

Comment: I think generators may be useful here. But doesn't the new ECMAScript have a `forEach` function on objects?

Comment: `Object.keys(yourObject).forEach(function(value){your code})`

Comment: _"This hack has made the "for in" statement all but useless in JavaScript."_ - No it hasn't. Sometimes you actually _want_ the loop to return inherited properties.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that people would bristle at that.

Comment: I'm not bristling at that, but I'm bristling at you saying I'm bristling. Seriously though, a `for..in` loop will only be broken if you've got people adding to the base object prototype, and that's reasonably easy to avoid on pages that you control. For situations where you want to be extra sure you have functions like Hogan's (below).

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you want

```
window.whatFor = function(obj,funct) {
   for (var v in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(v)) {
         funct(v);
      }
   }
}
```

Then.

```
whatFor(sam, function (x) { alert(x); } );
```

[Fiddle it up](http://jsfiddle.net/wTSmu/) - because, why not?

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see why you're attaching `whatFor` to the `window` object. Doing so will make your code browser specific. You won't even be able to use it in web workers.

This is what I would do:

```
var global = typeof global !== "undefined" ? global :
             typeof self !== "undefined" ? self : this;

global.whatFor = whatFor;

function whatFor(object, callback) {
    var hasOwn = {}.hasOwnProperty.bind(object);

    for (var property in object)
        if (hasOwn(property))
            callback(property);
}
```

You may have noticed that instead of calling `object.hasOwnProperty(property)` I'm calling `hasOwn(property)` instead. This is because the `hasOwnProperty` method may not exist in the prototype chain of the object.

Comment: Wow Aadit!  Thank you.  The reason why I used window is because I didn't know not to - I was under the impression that window WAS the global scope.  Man, I have a lot to learn!

Comment: @Phillip - You're welcome. You're right - `window` IS the global scope, but try using it in node.js or a web worker: http://www.doingitwrong.com/