# Changing the "for in" statement

Tags: javascript

Could I change the "for in" statement to include the following condition?

```
if (object.hasOwnProperty(variable) {
}
```

Comment: What `for in` statement?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445033/a-custom-for-in-statement ?

Comment: or use `Object.keys(yourObject).forEach(function(value){your code})`

Comment: Are you asking how to permanently "fix" the `for..in` statement so that that test happens automatically? If so you can't do that, but you can easily code a function to do the equivalent and then call that function whenever you need a `for..in`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in the loop:

```
for (var i in o) {
    if (!o.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;

    ...
}
```

The MDN has [an example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty#Example%3a_Itarate_over_properties_not_considering_inherited_properties) similar to this.